# What does the actual parameter A[i] refer to in this example of call by value-result?

Tags: programming-languages

From Programming Languages: Principles and Paradigms, by Maurizio Gabbrielli, Simone Martini

> ```
> void fiefoo (valueresult int x, valueresult int y) {
> x = x+1;
> y = 1;
> }
> ...
> int i = 1;
> int[] A = new int[5];
> A[1]=4;
> fiefoo(i,A[i]);
> ```
>
> we are to execute `fiefoo` with parameters passed by value-result. On
>   termination, we will have `A[1]` with value `1` and `i` with value
>   `2`, while the rest of the array `A` has not been touched.

Why is it `A[1]` instead of `A[2]` whose value is `1`?

My thought is that when returning from the function `fiefoo`, `x`'s value `2` is assigned to `i`, so `A[i]` is evaluated to be `A[2]`, and `y`'s value `1` is assigned to `A[i]`.

My thought is according to what the book says

> It should be clear that, as in call by value, the following questions
>   about **evaluation order in call by return** must be answered. If
>   there is more than one result parameter, in which order (for example,
>   from left to right) should the corresponding “backward assignment”
>   from the actual to formal be performed?
>
> Finally, **when is the actual parameter’s l-value determined**? It is
>   reasonable to determine it both when the function is called and when
>   it terminates. We can construct an example which gives different
>   results if the l-value of the actual is determined at call time or
>   when the procedure terminates.

Thanks.

Comment: There is nice explanation how [call by value-result vs by reference differs](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6549/call-by-value-result-vs-call-by-reference)

Answer (score 3):

This example is to get readers to think about the consequences of how `A[i]` is resolved in a call by value-result setting- should it be before or after the function call to fiefoo?

The example assumes that `A[i]` is resolved before the call, and hence `i` and `A[1]` are assigned values `1` and `2` respectively. It has the nice property that `fiefoo` can only modify those variables.

On the other hand, you can imagine a programming language designer who chooses to resolve the value of `A[i]` after `fiefoo` returns, but there's two possible outcomes depending on the order in which the value-results are assigned: 1) `A[old i] = y`, `i = x`; and 2) `i = x`, `A[updated i]`. Case #2 being what you proposed.

When the designer is faced with these design decisions, she would likely opt to resolve before the call to `fiefoo` to avoid the possible ambiguity associated with resolving after the call to `fiefoo`.